# how to get only active relationships in laravel eloquent in when

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

hi i have a when eloquent clause that i want to pick only the properties that has active relation of discount so my code is like below :

```
->when($has_discount, function ($query, $has_discount) {
            $query->with([
                'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function ($q) use ($has_discount) {
                    $q->has('discount');
                }
            ]);
```

i will go for my hotels and then inside that i pick rooms and i want to pick hotels with active relation of discount on room  but this code right now is doing nothing for me how can i achive that ??

Comment: Without Model Name or Table name how to derive solution ! @Farshad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the closer function in which set condition
like that

```
$query->with([
            'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function ($q) use ($has_discount) {
                $q->where('discount', 'active');
            }
        ]);
```